# My automatic paragraph slideshow not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I am facing a problem where my paragraphs inside my slideshow container are not showing. I have tried putting the JS in front of the body closing tag and also adding body onload = showSlides(). I feel like the display: none in CSS is blocking it, but I do not know. Really thankful for any help

```js
// SLIDESHOW
var slideIndex = 0;

showSlides();
function showSlides() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1};
    
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    setInterval(showSlides, 2000);
    };
```

```css
/* SLIDESHOW */


.facts {background-color: lightblue;
        position: relative;
        float: right;
        display: block;
        clear: both;
        margin-top: -34%;
        border-radius: 10%;
        text-align: center;
        overflow: visible;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0
    }

.mySlides {
    display: none;
    padding: 5%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: visible;
    margin: 0

}
```

```html
<aside>
    <div class="facts">
    <h2>Facts about German language</h2>

    <div class="mySlides">
        <p style="width:100%">German is the 11th most widely spoken language in the world</p>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
        <p>English and German share 60% of their vocabulary</p>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
        <p>Besides Germany, German is the official language of both Austria and Liechtenstein and one of the official languages in Switzerland and Luxembourg</p>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  </aside>
```

Comment: First step, you need to use `getElementsByClassName`. Notice that `Elements` is plural.

Comment: `"Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByClassName is not a function"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1. It should be getElementsByClassName
2. In your CSS for `facts` you have  `margin-top: -34%;` which makes it where you can see anything

```js
// SLIDESHOW
var slideIndex = 0;


function showSlides() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1};
    
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    setInterval(showSlides, 2000);
    };
    
    showSlides();
```

```css
/* SLIDESHOW */


.facts {
         background-color: lightblue;
        position: relative;
        float: right;
        display: block;
        clear: both;
       
        border-radius: 10%;
        text-align: center;
        overflow: visible;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0
    }

.mySlides {
    display: none;
    padding: 5%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: visible;
    margin: 0

}
```

```html
<aside>
    <div class="facts">
    <h2>Facts about German language</h2>

    <div class="mySlides">
        <p style="width:100%">German is the 11th most widely spoken language in the world</p>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
        <p>English and German share 60% of their vocabulary</p>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
        <p>Besides Germany, German is the official language of both Austria and Liechtenstein and one of the official languages in Switzerland and Luxembourg</p>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  </aside>
```